# JPA/Hibernate : How to annotate lazy fetch when column name is different?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I need to do lazy fetch on a column that has different name in table than my jpa/hibernate entity's attribute name. I have done it this way:

```
 @Column(name = "outlier_multiplier", precision = 65535, scale = 4)
 @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 public BigDecimal getKateOutlierMultiplier() {
       return kateOutlierMultiplier;
 }
```

Is this right way of annotating a column when the name is different in the table and in hibernate entity?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: Yes this is a [right way](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-lazy-loading). But please note that it will not work without bytecode enhancement.